# vários valores para uma coluna no Where

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, lógica, tabela-banco-de-dados

Existe alguma forma de colocar vários valores para uma coluna no `WHERE`?

Por exemplo o produto A foi substituído pelo produto B,

o produto 2933 pelo 4044,
o produto 2599 pelo 7845,
e o produto 5987 pelo 9432.

Exemplo:

```
where DepartureDate between '20161120' and '20161120' 
        AND datediff(day, DataVersao, DepartureDate) between 0 and 100
        and Segment = 'VCPCNF' 
        and Produto in ('2933','4044')
        and Produto in ('5987','9432')
        and Produto in ('2599','7845')
```

O que ocorre é que tenho 30 dias de venda do produto 2933
mas no 10o décimo dia ele muda de código de número e passa a ser 4044. 
Quando coloco numa tabela para analisar o resultado de vendas, tenho metade no 2933 e metade no 4044. Dai eu junto os dois resultados and Produto in ('2933','4044') e tenho completo.

Mas no meu caso, eu quero que ele traga o resultado do produto 2933 que foi substituido pelo produto 4044. Em seguida trazer o resultado do produto 5987 que foi substituido pelo resultado do numero 9432. Em seguida trazer o resultado do produto 2599 que foi substituido pelo resultado do numero 7845. Trazer de uma só vez sem ter que ficar rodando um a um. Por isso separei como ('2933','4044'), ('5987','9432') e ('2599','7845')

Comment: Está com algum problema fazendo isto?

Comment: Tem que trocar por ( Produto IN ... OR Produto IN ... ), não tem como ser verdadeira a condição atual (ou idealmente um IN só)

Comment: Estou, primeiro ele não funciona e não traz os valores. Segundo eu quero que ele traga numa tabela só os valores do produto A que foi substituido pelo Produto B. Então vai me trazer valores do '2933', '5987', '2599' mas esses substituiram o segundo numero dentro dos parenteses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### O Problema da query original:

Primeiro, sua condição seria sempre falsa, precisaria de um `OR` e `( )` se fosse manter a mesma estrutura:

```
 where DepartureDate between '20161120' and '20161120' 
    AND datediff(day, DataVersao, DepartureDate) between 0 and 100
    and Segment = 'VCPCNF' 
    and ( Produto in ('2933','4044')
          or Produto in ('5987','9432')
          or  Produto in ('2599','7845') )
```

No seu caso, o `AND` implicaria que todos os `IN` resultassem em verdadeiro, o que é impossível sendo que cada lista tem valores diferentes.

No caso, como já mencionado, você poderia usar um `IN` só com vários ítens, e nem usar o `OR`.

O que pode acontecer é você precisar de `IIF` (versão 2012+) ou `CASE .. WHEN` para alternar os valores, caso queira que fique só o mais atual na exibição.

### Substituindo na saída:

Dependendo da situação, seria o caso de um `REPLACE` na tabela original, mas em muitas situações, você precisa de rastreabilidade, ou da preservação da informação original. Neste caso, pode alterar os dados na saída apenas quando precisar.

Se quer os valores modificados, pode fazer algo assim:

```
SELECT
  CASE  
    WHEN campo='2933' THEN '4044'
    WHEN campo='5987' THEN '9432'
    WHEN campo='2599' THEN '7845'
    ELSE campo
  END
  AS campo_substituido
```

Se quiser SOMENTE os que estão na lista:

```
SELECT
  CASE  
    WHEN campo='2933' THEN '4044'
    WHEN campo='5987' THEN '9432'
    WHEN campo='2599' THEN '7845'
    ELSE '?'
  END
  AS campo_substituido
WHERE campo IN ( '2933', '4044', '5987', '2599', '2599', '7845' )
```

O `ELSE` está aí mais para mostrar a sintaxe correta, no segundo caso ele não ocorreria.

Comment: O motor do SQL vai trocar a lógica da sua query por um único `in` de qualquer forma.

Comment: O que ocorre é que tenho 30 dias de venda do produto 2933 mas no 10o décimo dia ele muda de código de número e passa a ser 4044. Quando coloco numa tabela para analisar o resultado de vendas, tenho metade no 2933 e metade no 4044. Dai eu junto os dois resultados and Produto in ('2933','4044') e tenho completo.

Comment: @Thais ai o que você quer é agrupamento pelo numero, o que nao estava na sua pergunta original. De qualquer forma, pode usar a mesma técnica do CASE WHEN, e agrupar pelo numero de saida (que vai ser sempre um só)

Comment: @Bacco tentei algo como case mas ainda não consegui o resultado esperado. Agrupar os dois em um só resultado.

Comment: @Thais um dos jeitos é passar o CASE para o GROUP BY, ficando assim: GROUP BY CASE WHEN campo='aaaa' THEN 'bbbb' WHEN .... END - é a mesma coisa que está na resposta, mas no caso em vez de por na lista de campos do SELECT você poe o CASE ... END no GROUP BY (e nao precisa do AS, no caso)

Answer (score 2):

A cláusula `in` aceita uma quantidade ilimitada de parâmetros. Logo, você pode fazer:

```
--SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ('fulano', 'beltrano', 'cricano', 'Palmeiras não tem mundial', 'etc')
```

No seu caso específico:

```
SELECT * FROM suaTabela
where DepartureDate between '20161120' and '20161120' 
        AND datediff(day, DataVersao, DepartureDate) between 0 and 100
        and Segment = 'VCPCNF' 
        and Produto in ('2933','4044', '5987','9432', '2599','7845')
```

Comment: Então no meu caso, eu quero que ele traga o resultado do produto 2933 que foi substituido pelo produto 4044. Em seguida trazer o resultado do produto 5987 que foi substituido pelo resultado do numero 9432. Em seguida trazer o resultado do produto 2599 que foi substituido pelo resultado do numero 7845. Trazer de uma só vez sem ter que ficar rodando um a um. Por isso separei como   ('2933','4044'), ('5987','9432') e ('2599','7845')

Answer (score 2):

```
and Produto in ('2933','4044,'5987','9432','2599','7845')
```

ou

```
and ( Produto in ('2933','4044') or
      Produto in ('5987','9432') or
      Produto in ('2599','7845') )
```

mas não entendi a questão do

> Por exemplo o produto A foi substituído pelo produto B,

Comment: Porque chega uma determinada data que apagam o registro de A pois foi substituido por outro numero tipo B, mas continua o mesmo produto.  
Então no meu caso, eu quero que ele traga o resultado do produto 2933 que foi substituido pelo produto 4044. Em seguida trazer o resultado do produto 5987 que foi substituido pelo resultado do numero 9432. Em seguida trazer o resultado do produto 2599 que foi substituido pelo resultado do numero 7845. Trazer de uma só vez sem ter que ficar rodando um a um. Por isso separei como ('2933','4044'), ('5987','9432') e ('2599','7845').